# Populating 3x3 bit cubes for every possible permutation

Tags: c#

I want to build up a collection of 3x3 cubes that contain bit (boolean) values. I would like the collection to contain every possible combination of values. So for 27 bits, every possible combination where each bit is on or off.

```
var dimension = 3;
var cubes = new List<bool[,,]>();

// iterate from (0,0,0) to (3,3,3)
var cube = new bool[dimension, dimension, dimension];
for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < dimension; k++)
        {
            cube[i, j, k] = true;
        }
    }
}
cubes.Add(cube);
```

This creates a single cube where each cell is set to true. How can I create all the other cubes to represent each possible permuation?

Comment: Are the cubes oriented?

Comment: can you clarify the question? creating some number of cubes is fine, but it isn't clear to me what the contents of an arbitrary cube would be (or indeed what the purpose of that cube would be) - note that there's 134 million permutations in 27 bits... and right now each cube takes about 120 bytes, so... that's 16 GiB of data (did you mean 9 bits?)

Comment: Just create a loop from `0x000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` to `0x111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` and then assign each bit of that number a position in the cube structure. Each cube you have is easily represented with a number.

Comment: You know that `(0,0,0) to (3,3,3)` is a `4×4×4` cube right (64 bits)?

Comment: Also instead of `bool[]` use `System.Collections.BitArray` instead.

Comment: You realize that's a hundred million cubes, right? This sounds like a classic "XY" problem. You have a real problem, you have a crazy idea of how to solve it, and now you are asking us to help you with your crazy idea. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Also, you say you are iterating from (0,0,0) to (3,3,3) but you are actually iterating to (2, 2, 2) which is correct.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the entire notion of creating a cube here is redundant and **massively** inefficient in terms of memory.

When you're asking "what are the bits in the positions of the Nth 3x3 cube", what you're *actually* asking here is : "what are the binary digits of N, a 27-bit number".

For *that*, you don't need to store or compute **anything** - you just need to do bit arithmetic on an `int` (since an `int` is 32 bits, and you only need 27). So: take `int n`, and use any combination of the bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `>>`, etc) - and *that's it* - no cubes, no list, no anything to store or pre-compute - just bits of an `int`. Working with the bits of an individual `int` is **staggeringly** efficient - much cheaper than even looking them up from a pre-computed `bool[,,]`. And the memory cost is literally zero, instead of 16GiB for the pre-computed option.

Answer (score 1):

First you can generate permutations of 27 bits.
For example

```
000000000000000000000000000 
100000000000000000000000000 
010000000000000000000000000 
... 
111111111111111111111111111
```

After that you just have to assign these permutations to the values of the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all value from 0 to 111111111111111111111111111 in binary notation. And put the appropriate values in the cells.

```
private void SetCubeValue(bool[, , ] cube, int dimension, int value)
{
    var bitArray = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));

    int dimensionX2 = dimension*dimension;
    int dimensionX3 = dimensionX2*dimension;

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensionX3; ++i)
    {
        int x = i / dimensionX2;
        int y = (i - x* dimensionX2) / dimension;
        int z = i -  x* dimensionX2 - y*dimension;

        if (i < bitArray.Length && bitArray[i])
            cube[x, y, z] = true;
    }
}
```

```
var dimension = 3;
var cubes = new List<bool[,,]>();

for (var i = 0; i < 134217727; ++i)
{
    var cube = new bool[dimension, dimension, dimension];
    SetCubeValue(cube, dimension, i);
    cubes.Add(cube);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple bin 0 is dec 0 bin 111111111111111111111111111 is dec 134217272 so you must create a loop from 0 to 134217272  and store the digit as binary with Convert.ToString(value, 2);
Because is not very clear the desired output format try this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < 134217727; i++)
{
   var strBin = Convert.ToString( i,2);
   // Do whatever you want with strbin
}
```